# Reload a current viewcontroller in tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbarcontroller

Currently I have a view controller that when you tap on the tab at index 3 (Map Tab) it loads a view controller that contains a map (Map A). **NOTE: it should always load Map A every time the Map Tab is pressed.**  There is a chiclet at index 0 on the main tab that when tapped allows you to switch from Map A to Map B and then takes you to that map (This switch is done manually so to keep the tab bar on screen using the tab bar's selectedIndex which means the viewWillAppear() doesnt seem to be called).   **NOTE: Map A and Map B share the same viewController, a bool is used to differentiate which one to load in viewWillAppear.**.The issue I'm having is after the chiclet is pressed to switch from Map A to Map B, once I hit the Map Tab again on the tab bar it automatically loads the current map I was just on (Map B), but as stated earlier, when pressed from tab bar, it should only load Map A.

This is what I was trying but it still won't show the proper map after the tab has been pressed:

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        switch viewController {
case is MapViewController:
            let nc = NotificationCenter.default
            nc.post(name: Notification.Name("changeMapStatus"), object: nil)
}
}
```

class MapViewController: BaseViewController {

```
    var mapBSelected: Bool = false

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        mapBSelected ? setupMapB() : setupMapA()
}

    @objc func changeMapStatus() {
          guard let mainTabController = tabBarController as? MainTabBarController else { return }
              mainTabController.refreshMapTab()
        self.MapBSelected = false
    }
```

}

```
   func refreshMapTab() {
             let index = PrimaryFeatureTab.map.displayOrder// enum to determine tab order
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      self.viewControllers?.remove(at: index)
                      self.viewControllers?.insert(PrimaryFeatureTab.map.rootViewController, at: index)
                  }
        }
}
```

Comment: You are probably better off handling that when the user leaves `MapTab`. Implement either `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` in your `MapViewController' class and reset the map and selector to "A" states. You won't need anything in your custom Tab Bar Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

---

Create a closure in your FirstViewController like this:

```
enum MapType {
    case mapA
    case mapB
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var mapSelectionClosure: ((MapType) -> Void)?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func aTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        mapSelectionClosure?(.mapA)
    }

    @IBAction func bTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        mapSelectionClosure?(.mapB)
    }

}
```

Then you can set this closure in your MainTabBarController like this

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let mainViewController = viewControllers?.first(where: { $0 is MainViewController }) as? MainViewController else {
            return
        }
        mainViewController.mapSelectionClosure = { mapType in
            self.setMapType(mapType)
        }

    }

    func setMapType(_ type: MapType) {
        guard let mapViewController = viewControllers?.first(where: { $0 is MapViewController }) as? MapViewController else {
            return
        }
        mapViewController.selectedMapType = type
    }

}
```

Comment: This is good but the setup is a bit different, the only way to get to Map A is through the tab bar so an iIBAction isn't used.

Comment: The IBAction is just an example and it is not switching the tab! 
It calls the closure to notify the MainTabBarController
Then the MainTabBarController notifies the MapViewController

Comment: Ok, but what if the map changes after the viewDidLoad is called on the MainTabBarController, how does it know to set the map type?

Comment: Then the closure body will get executed again if you call `mapSelectionClosure?(.mapB)` from your MainViewController

Comment: But the only way to get to Map A is through tapping the tab bar not in the viewController. So  you would call the closure on the MainViewController after the tab bar tab has been pressed?

Answer (score 0):

In `MapViewController`...

```
class MapViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.setupMapA()
    }

}
```

Now, when you ***leave*** the Map Tab, it will reset itself to Map A.

No need for any code in a custom TabBarController.